# Powershell to HTML - I can't add a break/new line between each Server 'Disk Space' info

Tags: html, powershell

I have the following Powershell script to query the Uptime/Disk Space/Memory Usage on several remote VM's, but the results that are produced are bunched together and as I add the remaining Servers to this script (about 30/40 odd more to be added) the data starts to become un-readable.

```
[CmdLetBinding()]
Param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)][string]$path = "C:\LON3 Web Server Report - $(get-date -f dd_MM_yyyy).html", 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)][array]$servers = @("Svr1","Svr2","Svr3")
)

Function Get-UpTime 
{ Param ([string[]]$servers) 
  Foreach ($s in $servers)  
   {  
     $os = Get-WmiObject -class win32_OperatingSystem -cn $s  
     New-Object psobject -Property @{  
       Uptime = ((get-date) - $os.converttodatetime($os.lastbootuptime)).Days 
       Hostname=$s  
         }
        }     
       } 

Function Get-DiskSpace 
{ 
 Param ([string[]]$servers) 
  Foreach ($s in $servers)  
   {  
     Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -cn $s |
       Select-Object @{LABEL='Server';EXPRESSION={$s}}, 
         driveletter, label,
         @{LABEL=" Total (GB)"; Expression = {" {0:N2} " -f ($_.capacity / 1GB)}}, 
         @{LABEL=" Free Space (GB) ";EXPRESSION={" {0:N2} " -f ($_.freespace/1GB)}},
         @{LABEL=" Percent Free (%) ";Expression = { "{0:N2} " -f (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) }},
         @{LABEL=" Percent Usage (%) ";Expression = {" {0:N2} " -f ((($_.Capacity - $_.freespace)/$_.Capacity)*100) }}           
    }
}

Function Get-MemoryUsage 
{ 
 Param ([string[]]$servers) 
  Foreach ($s in $servers)  
   {  
     Get-WmiObject -Class win32_OperatingSystem -cn $s |
       Select-Object @{LABEL='Server';EXPRESSION={$s}}, 
         @{LABEL=" Total Physical Memory (MB) "; Expression = {" {0:N0} " -f (($_.totalvisiblememorysize / 1024))}},
         @{LABEL=" Free Physical Memory (MB) "; Expression = {" {0:N0} " -f (($_.freephysicalmemory / 1024))}},
         @{LABEL=" Total Virtual Memory (MB) "; Expression = {" {0:N0} " -f (($_.totalvirtualmemorysize / 1024))}}, 
         @{LABEL=" Free Virtual Memory (MB) "; Expression = {" {0:N0} " -f (($_.freevirtualmemory / 1024))}}     
    }
}

$upTime = Get-UpTime -servers $servers |  
ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment -PreContent " 
  Created on: $(get-date)
  <h2>Server Uptime</h2> " | Out-String 

$disk = Get-DiskSpace -servers $servers |  
ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment -PreContent " 
  <h2>Disk</h2> "| Out-String

$memory = Get-MemoryUsage -servers $servers |  
ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment -PreContent " 
  <h2>Memory Usage</h2> "| Out-String     


$head = @'
<style media='screen'>
body {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table{
border-collapse: collapse;
border: none;
font: 10pt Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table td{
font-size: 12px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 20px;
text-align: left;
}

table th {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 20px;
text-align: left;
}

h2{ clear: both; font-size: 130%;color:#354B5E; }

h3{
clear: both;
font-size: 75%;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;
color:#475F77;
}

p{ margin-left: 20px; font-size: 12px; }

table.list{ float: left; }

table.list td:nth-child(1){
font-weight: bold;
border-right: 1px grey solid;
text-align: right;
}

table.list td:nth-child(2){ padding-left: 7px; }
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even){ background: #BBBBBB; }
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){ background: #F2F2F2; }
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd){ background: #DDDDDD; }
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even){ background: #E5E5E5; }
div.column { width: 320px; float: left; }
div.first{ padding-right: 20px; border-right: 1px grey solid; }
div.second{ margin-left: 30px; }
table{ margin-left: 20px; }
–>
</style>
<style media='print'>

</style>
'@

ConvertTo-Html -Head $head -PreContent "<h1>Daily Status Report - SQL Servers</h1>" -PostContent $upTime, $disk, $memory >> $path  
Invoke-Item $path
```

This image below makes it easier to understand. I basically need a 'new line' or 'break' to show between each Server (marked with a 'Red' line), but I can't figure out the Powershell/HTML coding to make this happen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish a separation is probably just to add an empty object at the bottom of each collection, Will at the very least give you a line break between each server.  so you would add something like this at the bottom of the `Get-DiskSpace` function

```
Function Get-DiskSpace 
{ 
 Param ([string[]]$servers) 
  Foreach ($s in $servers)  
   {  
     Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -cn $s |
       Select-Object @{LABEL='Server';EXPRESSION={$s}}, 
         driveletter, label,
         @{LABEL=" Total (GB)"; Expression = {" {0:N2} " -f ($_.capacity / 1GB)}}, 
         @{LABEL=" Free Space (GB) ";EXPRESSION={" {0:N2} " -f ($_.freespace/1GB)}},
         @{LABEL=" Percent Free (%) ";Expression = { "{0:N2} " -f (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) }},
         @{LABEL=" Percent Usage (%) ";Expression = {" {0:N2} " -f ((($_.Capacity - $_.freespace)/$_.Capacity)*100) }}           
}
    [PsCustomObject]@{Server = "";driveletter = "";label = ""; "Total (GB)" = ""; "Free Space (GB)" = ""; "Percent Free (%)" = ""; "Percent Usage (%)" = ""}
```

}

Note that this is probably not the *best* way to go as it's hard to extend that methodology to other scripts but it will accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: My apologies, appears I mistyped a quote.  but it should work if you modify your `Get-DiskSpace` function as I've added to the answer.

Comment: you absolute legend! Thank you, work's perfectly! was annoying me that lol as theres say 4 drives for each of the 30 odd servers! Trying to figure out a really simple Powershell Form to have 4 buttons on to run 4 of these scrips/.ps1

Comment: Happy I could help!  If your just getting started working with WPF to create GUI's you may want to take a look at some of the articles here - https://learn-powershell.net/ (navigating the site to find his WPF articles can be a bit tricky but there are a few of them there) or for a more basic primer you can check out a blog post I did on the topic here - http://www.poshscript.org/powershell-input-box/  Just a note if you use that method that the GUI will lock up while the scripts run in the background, you can overcome that with runspaces but there is significantly more code involved.